# SQL Server : delete specific data after searching column name in whole database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table CenterDetails like this

```
| uid | CenterID | CenterName | AccessLock |
| ----|----------|------------|------------|
|1    |  1       |  Andheri   |    1       |
|2    |  2       |  Borivali  |    1       |
|1    |  3       |  Dadar     |    1       |
```

I have 100's of tables in my database.

If I want to delete Dadar center, then first I need to check, to the whole database, where `centerID=3` exist or not.

If dadar center's `CenterID` does not exist in the whole database where column names are `CenterID`.

How can I find that `CenterID=3` is present in the whole database or not?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code will help you:

```
DECLARE @ColumnName SYSNAME = 'CenterID '
       ,@ColumnValue NVARCHAR(256) = '3'

DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @DynamicSQLStatement  =STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ' UNION ALL ' + CHAR(10)  + ' SELECT TOP 1 ''' + t.name + ''' AS T FROM ' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.name + ' WHERE ' +  @ColumnName + ' =  ' + @ColumnValue + CHAR(10)
        FROM sys.tables t 

        INNER JOIN sys.columns c
            on t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
        WHERE c.[name] = @ColumnName
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
   ,1
   ,12
   ,''
);

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatement
```

It is looking for all tables that have specific column. Then it query all these tables in order to find if the given column has a specific value, if yes, it will return the table name.

What will  be better here is to read about data integrity or more specific the foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

---

Hope it helps you

```
DECLARE @TablesColumns TABLE
    (
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(50),
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(50)
    )
    DECLARE @MinId INT,
            @MaxId INT,
            @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @TableName VARCHAR(50),
            @ColumnName VARCHAR(50)

    INSERT INTO @TablesColumns(COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME)--Here we get list of table containing 'centerID'
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME='Credits'

    SELECT @MinId=MIN(Id) FROM @TablesColumns
    SELECT @MaxId=MAX(Id) FROm @TablesColumns


    WHILE (@MinId <=@MaxId)
    BEGIN
    SELECT @TableName=TABLE_NAME FROm @TablesColumns WHERE Id=@MinId
    SELECT @ColumnName=COLUMN_NAME FROm @TablesColumns WHERE Id=@MinId
    SET @Sql='DELETE From ' +@TableName+ ' WHERE '+@ColumnName+'=3'
    --PRINT @Sql
    SET @MinId=@MinId+1
    Exec (@Sql)
    END
```